# How to create dynamic chart in PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, charts, phpexcel

I have problem with getting data from SQL Database to a dynamic Chart in PHPExcel

SQL code

```
` $qry = "SELECT * FROM t_category 
  ORDER BY id_category";
      $sql = mysql_query($qry);
      while ($showcategory= mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

            $id_category = $showcategory['id_category'];
            $name_category = $showcategory['name_category'];

            $qry2 = "SELECT SUM(stock) AS total_stok FROM t_product WHERE id_category ='$id_category'";

            $sql2= mysql_query($qry2);

            $datastock = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);  

            echo $showcategory['name_category']." :".$datastock ['total_stok']."<br/>"; 

      }`
```

Which gives output as follows :

```
product1 : 20
product2 : 30
product3 : 10
```

And So On..

The Question is how to make these SQL output become dynamic array that would be Implemented on PHPExcel like this

```
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
 array(
    array('',   Product 1,  Product2,   Product3,  And So On...),
    array('Stock',   20,   30,  10, And So On...),

 )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
$i = 0;
while ($showcategory= mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
...   
    $objWorksheet->write($i, 0, $showcategory['name_category']);
    $objWorksheet->write($i, 1, $datastock ['total_stok']);
    ++$i;
}
```